# Formula Excel - Apache POI

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Criei um arquivo do excel usando a API Apache Poi, nele eu setei uma das células com uma fórmula, porém quando eu abro o arquivo eu preciso "dar enter" na célula com a fórmula para que ela printe o resultado no arquivo. Teria uma forma de fazer esse resultado aparecer automaticamente?

código:

```
destino.getSheet("Status dos Testes").getRow(2).createCell(7).setCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
destino.getSheet("Status dos Testes").getRow(2).getCell(7).setCellFormula("CONT.SE($D$6:$D$10000, Legenda!A6)");
```

resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha esse exemplo :

```
public static void triggerFormula(HSSFWorkbook workbook){      

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int lastRowNo=sheet.getLastRowNum();        

            for(int rownum=0;rownum<=lastRowNo;rownum++){
            Row row;
             if (sheet.getRow(rownum)!=null){
                     row= sheet.getRow(rownum);

                  int lastCellNo=row.getLastCellNum();

                      for(int cellnum=0;cellnum<lastCellNo;cellnum++){  
                              Cell cell;
                              if(row.getCell(cellnum)!=null){
                                 cell = row.getCell(cellnum);   
                                if(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA==cell.getCellType()){
                                evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
                            }
                        }
                     }
             }
            }


        }
```

Comment: isso gera um erro:

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell 'Status dos Testes'!H3 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:359)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:300)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:232)
 at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:200)`

Comment: AAAH! Consegui usando isso sim! Obrigada